# Itunes Connect: You must have only 1 Leaderboard as default

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm getting the above error when I try to create the first leaderboard for my newest app. Does anyone know how to resolve the error?

I do have another app with a leaderboard but surely that won't affect this app. For reference, I'm trying to create a single leaderboard.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: same here. Can't seem to find a way around it.

Comment: Hi, I've raised a bug with Apple with a video of the issue. Hopefully, they will investigate soon, and then I will update you both.

Comment: Thanks. This is very likely indeed a QA issue with their latest itunes connect rollout.

Comment: No news yet, they have responded asking for more information and I have supplied it.

Comment: Same here, looks like an issue on Apple's side. Hopefully it'll be solved soon

Comment: Thanks @Chelsea for handling it. Of course, just them trying out the "create leaderboard" button ought to be sufficient to reproduce... Not sure how much more information you can provide :)

Comment: Yes, I suspect the person I was communicating with was just buying time/delaying the inevitable!

Comment: Same issue here. 

Comment: No updates - radio silence from apple today. However, I have found the following posts which have been created since I created mine:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66460
https://www.buildbox.com/forum/index.php?threads/create-a-leaderboard-is-not-working-on-ios.7616/

So I am fairly confident that it's a bug on Apple's end and I suspect they are probably aware of it at this point

Comment: Received confirmation they are working on the fix

Comment: Just verified and it has now been fixed. Thanks @Chelsea fr reporting the bug. Create away.

Comment: Guys, did you try updating an existing leaderboard? I can't do that and get an error. @Chelsea, if you get the issue, I suggest you extend the same ticket with Apple please. Otherwise I may have to tell them whole thing over again. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedSalmanTahir Tried and indeed got an error "A leaderboard with ID  ...  already exists.". While I appreciate Apple fixing the original issue, looks like they are rushing things out a bit these days without proper checks and balances in their db rollouts. This does point to another, new issue though, so a new bug report would likely make sense here.

Comment: I've reported this as a new problem with Apple (bug id 29003239). Will ping when I know more.

Comment: I've opened a new question to track the new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310350/itunes-connect-cant-edit-existing-leaderboard

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot @LoicArgelies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in iTunes Connect and was confirmed by Apple. The fix has now been released and you should be able to create leaderboards now.