# iTunes Connect: Can't edit existing leaderboard

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center-leaderboard

It looks like there is a recent problem with iTunes Connect which prevents editing (changing any detail) of existing leaderboards.

A few days ago iTunes Connect had an issue where we could not create a new leaderboard. As of last night a new deployment of iTunes Connect fixed that particular bug, although it seems like a new issue was introduced.

The new issue is now that an existing leaderboard can no longer be edited, failing with an error upon save. The text of the error suggests the changes made to the leaderboard in the iTunes Connect associated web page are in fact resubmitted to the server as a new leaderboard, instead of an update to an existing entry.

The error is 100% reproducible and says:

The following error(s) occurred:
- A leaderboard with ID " [leaderboard id] " already exists
- The Leaderboard Reference Name you entered has already been used. Enter a unique Reference Name and try again."

In my case, the leaderboard was part of a leaderboard set.

I have submitted a bug report to Apple and will update when I know more. unless anyone finds a workaround or more details.

Comment: even achievements also not possible to edit and recreate

Comment: You're right indeed. Not impressed.

Comment: iTunes connect is constantly having issues like this one

Comment: This is insane! Has Apple stopped testing its products before rolling them out? Didn't expect this from them!

Comment: Still no news from Apple. Continuing to monitor.

Comment: Unchanged. No response or status change from Apple on the bug report.

Comment: Want me to push this issue as part of my ticket? Might have more success :)

Comment: You could try, never hurts for sure... But I imagine that we are hardly the only ones raising this issue. For reference, I just created 118 leaderboards in two languages with unreasonable pain and extreme care not to make a single typo, because indeed there is no way to update and make any correction to leaderboards (or achievements, for that matter, from @Guru). Surely Apple must be aware by now, although they haven't bothered to update or respond to the ticket.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if there are actually that many people and devs using Game Center services out there by now, given what we could call a lack of love from their end and the recent move in iOS 10, removing the GC app. In any case, I'll continue to monitor and update.

Comment: Yeah I was very confused by the removal of the game center app, why did they do that?

Comment: I believe it was motivated by low adoption from the public at large, although it's hard to find hard evidence. It's been hinted at with the advent of iOS 10 in the press, and 3 years ago with iOS 8 Apple were already considering removal of the app in favour of a service. The social network aspect of GC might have stagnated...

Comment: See from 3 years ago: "Apple is considering removing the Game Center application from iOS. Instead of having the (little-used) Game Center app, the functionality will solely be found inside in games that have integrated the social gaming service." https://9to5mac.com/2014/03/14/ios-8-besides-new-apps-apple-to-focus-on-refining-its-new-beginning-for-iphone-ipad-software/

Comment: Not only is the GC app removed, you guys may have noticed that since iOS 10 came out, any new game or a new update that is going live does not display the banner depicting that the game supports GC. This means that the user can't know whether a game has GC or not until he actually installs it. I just can't understand that! Do you think Apple will eventually get rid of GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have finally fixed the issue and the leaderboards are editable again. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks for following it up with Apple and keeping us informed